# Getting Unexpected white spaces in pdf file converted from html

Tags: html

Actually we are converting html to pdf file using [gotenberg](https://thecodingmachine.github.io/gotenberg/#html) tool. In html the data looks fine but strangely in the pdf file it is getting some blank spaces within the divs. Can any one help to come out from this? Thanks.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrLKK.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62mZ9.png)

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your html looks like? What are those pictures? The expected results or the wrong results? If the latter, what is it supposed to look like instead?

Comment: Those are wrong results. There blank space should not be there.